# Variance of mutually exclusive events

Tags: probability, dice, variance, sampling

I am trying to calculate the variance of repeated, independent sampling of two mutually exclusive events, $X$ and $Y$. For example, $X$ could represent rolling a fair $6$-sided die and $Y$ rolling a loaded die that only lands on $2,3,4,5 or 6$ (all with $20%$ probability). If each time you roll, you reach into a bag and select either $X$ or $Y$, what is the variance of $n$ rolls?

For the example given and others like it, I know how to manually calculate the variance by calculating the expected value, the probability of each outcome, and the deviation of each outcome from the mean. However, for more complex problems this quickly becomes very tedious.

So, given $P(X) = p$ and $P(Y) = 1-p, Var(X), Var(Y)$, and any other necessary properties of these distributions, is there a formula to calculate the variance of n events without referring to the probabilities of individual outcomes (i.e. rolling a $3$)?

Comment: What do you mean by "variance of $n$ events?" Do you mean the variance of a sum of $n$ random variables, each of which is an independent experiment in which one of the two dice is selected at random and rolled?

Comment: Random variables have a variance (not events, unless you treat them as Bernoulli random variables). It seems that you make no distinction between random variables and events. Expression $\mathsf P(X)=p$ suggests that $X$ is an event, but expression $\mathsf{Var}(X)$ suggests that it is random variable.